# update packages repositories error

Tags: apt, updates, python3

```
sudo apt update
```

Can anyone help resolve this?

```
ERROR:
Fatal error: E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/b
in/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then /usr/lib/cn
f-update-db > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

File exists:

```
desktop:/usr/lib$ ls cnf-update-db 
cnf-update-db
```

File contents:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import glob
import logging
import os
import sys

from CommandNotFound.db.creator import DbCreator
from CommandNotFound import CommandNotFound


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if "--debug" in sys.argv[1:]:
        logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
    elif "--verbose" in sys.argv[1:]:
        logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    
    db = CommandNotFound.dbpath
    if not os.access(os.path.dirname(db), os.W_OK):
        print("datbase directory %s not writable" % db)
        sys.exit(0)

    command_files = glob.glob("/var/lib/apt/lists/*Commands-*")
    if len(command_files) > 0:
        col = DbCreator(command_files)
        col.create(db)
```

Comment: Worked, Thanks so much

Comment: Worked,,Thanks so much